# Ruby - How do I access keys from an array nested in a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm working on a small video game on the console where I have a main config hash that stores values for the game. When I try to access keys in an array in that hash, they don't return anything. Am I doing something wrong?

```
cfg =
{
    :gameVersion => 1.0,
    :invPouch => ['flint', 'string'],
    :gold => 50
}

puts cfg[:invPouch[1]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
puts cfg[:invPouch][1]
```

In your case, `:invPouch[1]` is `"n"`, and  `cfg["n"]` gives you `nil`.

Comment: answer in form of a runnable snippet: http://rubysandbox.com/#/snippet/5673f3fac55987000c000000